# Should I use a ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

A quick question about ConcurrentHashMap:

```
public Map<String, String> getA(){
get something from db in a HashMap lets call it x
....
 do some operations in on x
....
 put the result in ConcurrentHashMap lets call it A
.....
  return A 
}
```

Does it make sense to have a ConcurrentHashMap or should I go with a HashMap?

1.HashMap
 2.ConsurentHashMap

Comment: If you aren't using multithreading, you don't need that.

Comment: I've seen people use CHMaps to overcome limitations in algorithms where they would add/remove etries while iterating - do you fall in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on different threads or otherwise the data will be operated on at the same time (multithreaded delegate or the alike) , yes, use `ConcurrentHashMap`. Otherwise, `HashMap` should do (given the information you've provided).

Based on reading your pseudo code, I get the impression that you are **not** working on different threads and therefore HashMap *should* suffice.

Comment: Although even in multithreading a CHM only works better "when used appropriately" (and HM only breaks if used incorrectly) - if a lock is taken over the [C]HM for all relevant operations then..

Answer (score 0):

You might do better wrapping it in `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` if you don't want to worry about the clients of this method getting into race conditions when modifying/reading the map.